# Outlook VBA - Rule on Missed Lync Conversations

Tags: vba, outlook, lync

I currently have a rule/VBA combo on all received e-mails that sends a brief e-mail info (sender, subject) to another address. However, this rule does not work on missed Lync conversations that do pop up in the Inbox. Is there any way to work around this?

Current setup for e-mails is using the Rule when message is received, run a script. The script then composes and sends an e-mail based on information on the received item.

Thank you.

Comment: Missed Conversations do get saved in the Inbox. Regular conversations are saved under the "Conversation History" folder.

Comment: the missed conversation doesn't trigger the rule / macro cause outlook doesn't treat them as incoming message.  Here's a possible work around but it's kinda reluctant: http://stdout-dev-null.blogspot.ca/2013/09/how-to-process-outlook-rules-on-lync-im.html